# Can we still use routes={routes} for react-router v4?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

The following code works:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  ),
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

But if I put the routes into a file `routes.js`, and

```
import routes from "./routes";

ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <Router routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
  ),
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

and inside of `routes.js`:

```
export default (
  <Route exact path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
);
```

Then it doesn't work.  This worked before in `react-router@2.0.0-rc5`... so can we not use the form `routes={routes}` any more? How should it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can put routes inside Router

```
<Router>
 {routes}
</Router>
```